# How to create new button in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, xamarin.android

I'm really new in coding but I know a few things in `C#`.
I'm learning by myself just for the sake of it, for fun. 
I've made some little programs in console and now I'm learning `Xamarin`.

For now, I've followed the xamarin tutorials (those with the "phoneword" app).

I'm now working on another app for android and I would like to know how to create a new button in code.

*Example:*
On the main page, the user presses a button that creates a new page where he can fill a form. After he finished, a new button appear on the main page that leads to the form previously filled. 
So when the user open the app, he has to choose whether he opens a new form or accesses to the old form (because now there is a new button).

All I want to know is: how do I create this new button ?

I've look everywhere and can't find any working solution. I don't know if that matters, but all I can see is explanations for Xamarin.Forms and that's not what I'm using. I'm using Xamarin Native.

For example, I've tried :

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "Test";
b.Click += OnClick;
```

But it's not working. VS returns various errors. 
I understand that "Button()" needs parameters, but I don't know what to do.

Someone can give a little help, please ?

PS: I'm not a native speaker, so please don't mind some mistakes with English grammar.

Comment: "VS returns various errors" - it would be really helpful if you tell us what these errors are.

Comment: Xamarin Native can mean Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Mac, maybe even some other flavors so you first need to say what you actually do.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza : didn't do it on purpose. Sorry.

Comment: @IvanIčin as I wrote, it's for Android.

Comment: @Jason Below you can check screens I uploaded. Thanks for helping !

Comment: a) nobody wants to click a link from some unknown image host, b) the images are too small to read, c) please post the text of the errors, not screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create `parameters` of layout & than add those params to button like this

```
var params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);    
Button b = new Button(this);
b.SetText("Test",TextView.BufferType.Normal);
b.Click=OnClick;
b.LayoutParameters = params;
```

Or add layout in your in axml like this

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@id/linear_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Than in your activity get you `Layout` using `Id` & add button to it.

```
LinearLayout l_layout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.linear_layout);
l_layout.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
Button b = new Button(this);
b.Click=OnClick;
b.SetText("Test",TextView.BufferType.Normal);
l_layout.AddView(b);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have some issues with both ways. Here you can check what VS returns : [link](https://www.cjoint.com/c/HKvpUArJ5Vi) and [link](https://www.cjoint.com/c/HKvpWnN8yxi) . Thanks for helping !

Comment: @Jojojojo The screenshots are hard to read (for instance I can't see your OnClick method), which it is why it is bad practise to use them. It is best to copy and paste your code and format it here according to the guidelines.

Comment: @jojojo - For first part, do that inside 'OnCreate' method of your activity & your are not passing 'this' in button at right side as I provided code. Create 'OnClick' method too or you can comment that line.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 as a matter of fact, I noticed that I didn't and try it again, but I uploaded the wrong screen. Thanks

Comment: So, I did what you said (comment the OnClick line) plus I rewrote the ID line (android:id="@+id/linear_layout"), and now it's working. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

With this You can create the button You only need to add the size of the button and add it to some layout.

Xamarin.Forms

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Title";
```

Xamarin.Android

```
Button button = new Button(this); //if your using a fragment you have to use this.Activity
button.Text = "Title";
```

Xamarin.iOS

```
UIButton button = new UIButton();
button.SetTitle("Title", UIControlState.Normal);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried but I don't know how to add a layout. So I tried @CGPA6.4 's way but got errors as you can see below.

Comment: which platform are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

**Xamarin forms button example**

```
var Tittlebutton= new Button
    {
    Text = "Title"
    };
```